# *unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class budgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       
    budget_used        = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    budget_remain      = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_budget       = serializers.IntegerField(default=250000)

def get_budget_used(self, obj):
    budget_used = budget_u.objects.filter(
        user=obj.user
    ).aggregate(total=Sum('budget_stord__bytes'))['total'] or 0
    if budget_used > 250000:
        return 'you exceed the total budget limit'
    return f'budget : {(budget_used/1000)}'

def get_total_budget(self,obj):
            total_budget = 250000
            return f'total_budget: {(total_budget/1000)} ' 
  
def get_remain(self,obj):
             remain = (self.context.get(total_budget)) - (self.context.get(budget_used)) 
             return remain

    class Meta:
        model  = budget_u
        fields = ("budget_used","total_budget","budget_remain")
```

Any help when i run the code above aim getting Error

(self.context.get(total_budget)) - (self.context.get(budget_used)) TypeError:
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: becuase `self.context.get(total_budget)` is returing the value **`None`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context does not store values of intermediate calculations, it is a dictionary that is used, for example by a `ModelViewSet` to inject data into the serializer.

To make matters even worse, even if the context indeed behaved the way as you are using it, it would *still* not work, since the `get_budget_used` and `get_total_budget` methods, return *strings*. You can not subtract two strings from each other, what would `'foo' - 'bar'` mean? Or in this case `'total budget: 25000' - 'budget : 1425'`? This may look simple if you *interpret* the strings, but for Python these are just strings, and the operations need to be non-ambiguous, hence it makes no sense.

You can define methods that return the value, and then use these by calling the functions:

```
class budgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    # …
    
    def _budget_used(self, obj):
        return budget_u.objects.filter(
            user=obj.user
        ).aggregate(total=Sum('budget_stord__bytes'))['total'] or 0
    
    def _total_budget(self, obj):
        return 250000
    
    def get_budget_used(self, obj):
        budget_used = self._budget_used(obj)
        if budget_used > 250000:
            return 'you exceed the total budget limit'
        return f'budget : {(budget_used/1000)}'
    
    def get_total_budget(self, obj):
        total_budget = self._total_budget(obj)
        return f'total_budget: {(total_budget/1000)} ' 
      
    def get_remain(self,obj):
        return self._total_budget(obj) - self._budget_used(obj)
```